# vb.net clone previous row vdatagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, clone

I don’t know if this is possible, but I would like every new row created in my datagridview to be an exact copy of the last row before that... I’m using vb.net I see a lot on cloning the row from one datagrid to another but I want to copy the row and past it as a new instance within the one datagridview?

Comment: how is your datagridview populated is it from a datatable?

Comment: have you tried anything at all?